Testing difference in Difference for observations repeated over time pre- and post intervention, with control and intervention group
I want to assess whether the monthly payment of a bonus to health workers starting in January 2023 has increased the number of monthly supervisions conducted. The country has 26 provinces, out of which 13 were paid a bonus since January 2023. A monthly supervision score giving the proportion of supervisions actually conducted against their expected numbers (score between 0% and 100%) has been collected for each of the 26 provinces since January 2019, and visually, their pre-intervention and control group means follow a linear, parallel trend.
How do you estimate whether the slope of the mean scores for the 13 intervention and 13 control provinces are statistically equal before the intervention, and different since 2023. Is there a way to these trends in one graph in Excel?
